# AJAX call botched by DOM Traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am attempting to implement a Like / Dislike system with a counter.  I am having problems with my AJAX call, more specifically when I am trying to change the HTML of selected elements in the view after passing values to the DB.

The element in question is .likeCount, a class with about a dozen or so siblings.  If i simply use the selector $('.likeCount'), the AJAX call will actually successfully update the like count but it will do it for every instance of the class.  If i attempt to use DOM traversal (.closest, this, .parent, etc) the like count does not update until I refresh the page.

the up and downvote carry a $('like') class.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

  $('.like').on('click', function(event)
  {
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;
    $.ajax(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        cache: false,
        data: {isLike : isLike, postId : postId, _token : token},
        success: function()
        {
           //first function working great 
           //(changes the like button to a disklike button and visa versa)

            $.ajax(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlCount,
                cache: false,
                data: {postId : postId, _token : token},
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var likeCount = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[2].textContent;
                    $('likeCount').html(data["count"]);
                    console.log(data["count"]);
                }

            })      
        }       
    })      
})
```

})

The console.log spits out the correct count every time.

How do I select the currently active likeCount without botching my AJAX call?

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="row posts">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <header><h3>Recent Posts:</h3></header>
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            @if (Storage::disk('local')->has($post->user->id . '.jpg'))
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img src="{{ route('account.image', ['filename' => $post->user->id . '.jpg']) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            @else
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img src="default.gif" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            @endif
            <article class="post col-xs-10" id="post" data-postid={{ $post->id }}>
                <p class="post-body">{{ $post->body }}</p>
                <div class="info">
                    Posted by {{ $post->user->name }} on {{ $post->created_at }}
                </div>

                    <div class="likeCount">{{ $post->likes->where('like', '1')->count() }} other people liked this.</div>

                    <div class="interaction">
                        <a class="like btn upvote">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 1 ? 'You like this' : 'Like' : 'Like'}}</a> |
                        <a class="like btn downvote">{{ Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first() ? Auth::user()->likes()->where('post_id', $post->id)->first()->like == 0 ? 'You dislike this' : 'Dislike' : 'Dislike'}}</a>

                        @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                        |
                        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Delete</a> 
                        @endif
                    </div>
            </article>
        @endforeach
        <?php echo $posts->links(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your second call be in the success function?

Comment: Don´t use $('likeCount'), use $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1]) or smth similar

Comment: @Sandesire, thanks that was a typo.

Comment: @juvian I have tried that unfortunately it hasn't worked thus far.

Comment: I think you should add your html to the question. Since the log in the inner success function is working properly, it really seems that your problem is about traversing the DOM properly, so the html structure is key.

Comment: Sergeon is right, please provide your html. Btw: Tidy up your JS please. ;)

Comment: Just added markup, tidying up now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is incorrect DOM Traversal.

var likeCount should be:

```
$(event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[5]);
```

Using 'event' simplifies things when multiple elements share a class name.